# Database multiple tables trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a database with this structure:

- users

  - id
  - username
  - ........
  - user_status
- questions

  - id
  - asker_id
  - asked_id
  - ........
  - question_status
- answers

  - id
  - question_id
  - who_answer_id
  - ........
  - answer_status
- likes

  - id
  - liker_id
  - liked_id
  - ........
  - like_status

How can I make a trigger when I update user_status = 'deleted' to automatically set:

```
question_status = deleted
answer_status = deleted
like_status = deleted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does this trigger do?

- List item
- Define new trigger
- Check if user_status column is updated.
- Check if user_status is updated to 'deleted'
- Take id of that user, and change status of all of it's questions, answers, and likes to 'deleted'.

Code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER  user_delete BEFORE UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.user_status <> OLD.user_status
    THEN 
        IF STRCMP('deleted',NEW.user_status) = 0 THEN
            UPDATE question_status SET question_status = 'deleted' WHERE asker_id = NEW.id;
            UPDATE answers SET answer_status = 'deleted' WHERE who_answer_id = NEW.id;
            UPDATE likes SET like_status = 'deleted' WHERE liker_id = NEW.id;
        END IF;
        IF STRCMP('active',NEW.user_status) = 0 THEN
            UPDATE question_status SET question_status = 'active' WHERE asker_id = NEW.id;
            UPDATE answers SET answer_status = 'active' WHERE who_answer_id = NEW.id;
            UPDATE likes SET like_status = 'active' WHERE liker_id = NEW.id;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Possible flow you might notice later**

Just consider this scenario on your site, QuestionA was already 'deleted' by some moderator, now when user (which is poster of that question) is re-activated, all such moderated questions/answers would come back !

You should ideally have another status to decide that it was automatically deleted or manually. Maybe 'auto_delete' and 'delete' instead of just using 'delete'.

Comment: Yes it is, but you should ideally not update question like this on StackOverflow by attaching answer to it, instead you can suggest edit on already given answer. (Might be useful for in future to you...)

Comment: Sorry, I updated again. Is there any possibility to have _status field only to users_table and to make a trigger when select something from X table to check first if user_id from X table have user_status active or deleted and if deleted to return nothing?

Comment: @IonVasile I have changed the answer by adding `active` thing. Also have written a point as suggestion, you can think to implement something like it i.e. different flag to differentiate automatic deleting.

Comment: GOOD POINT! Thank you.

Comment: So regarding my last comment here, for example:

select * from questions where category_id = 5;

for each row returned I must make a join to users table to get users name and city
but if user is deleted do not return that row so is not need for _status to each table.

Comment: Yes it is possible too. But in that case, mysql might have to run those triggers too frequently, it would cause unnecessary load on your servers. I think you should go ahead with something like what I suggested. But still if you wish trigger for select query, I can provide you. Please let me know.

Comment: I added a new answer to my question . Should solve the flow. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL server (because I see no database specified) I would say do 1 trigger on table users as follows (may not be exact)

```
﻿CREATE TRIGGER [user_statusDeleted]
ON [users]
After UPDATE, INSERT --INSERT may not be relevant
AS 
BEGIN
UPDATE q
SET q.[question_status] = deleted
FROM [inserted] i 
    JOIN [questions] q
        ON i.[Id] = q.[asker_id] --or asked_id ?
        AND i.[user_status] = deleted
```

Then add two more updates for tables answers and likes after this one (sorry, I would be guessing the joins anyway), separated by semicolon and it should work.

more on triggers in sql server here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: Please check tags, he has mentioned it to be `mysql`

Comment: Sorry I must have missed that one

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN
    IF NEW.user_status <> OLD.user_status
    THEN 
        IF STRCMP('deleted',NEW.user_status) = 0 THEN
            UPDATE questions SET question_status = 'deleted' WHERE asker_id = NEW.id AND question_status != 'mod_deleted';
            UPDATE answers SET answer_status = 'deleted' WHERE commentator_id = NEW.id AND answer_status != 'mod_deleted';
            UPDATE likes SET like_status = 'deleted' WHERE liker_id = NEW.id AND like_status != 'mod_deleted';
        END IF;
        IF STRCMP('active',NEW.user_status) = 0 THEN
            UPDATE questions SET question_status = 'active' WHERE asker_id = NEW.id AND question_status != 'mod_deleted';
            UPDATE answers SET answer_status = 'active' WHERE commentator_id = NEW.id AND answer_status != 'mod_deleted';
            UPDATE likes SET like_status = 'active' WHERE liker_id = NEW.id AND like_status != 'mod_deleted';
        END IF;
    END IF;
END
```

_status fields are enum type so if I add mod_deleted and in the update I add a AND should solve the flow